# Обработка вложенной таблицы в json запросе

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Создал программу на основе примера из [Android Begin](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-jsoup-listview-images-texts-html-tables-tutorial/). Убрал все лишнее, чтобы переделать под свои нужды. Но дело в том, что таблица находится внутри таблицы первая по порядку. Получилась такая ерунда (которая само собой не запустилась):

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.kovalev.jsoupkakiepary;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ListView listview;
  ListViewAdapter adapter;
  ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
  ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> arraylist;
  static String RANK = "rank";
  static String COUNTRY = "country";
  static String POPULATION = "population";
  static String FLAG = "flag";
  // URL Address
  String url = "http://www.kakiepary.ru/archive/num/45/";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new JsoupListView().execute();
  }

  private class JsoupListView extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, Void > {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      // Create a progressdialog
      mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
      // Set progressdialog title
      mProgressDialog.setTitle("KakiePary");
      // Set progressdialog message
      mProgressDialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
      mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
      // Show progressdialog
      mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {
      // Create an array
      arraylist = new ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> ();

      try {
        // Connect to the Website URL
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        // Identify Table Class "worldpopulation"
        for (Element table: doc.select("table[id=child_time]")) {

          // Identify all the table row's(tr)
          for (Element row: table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
            HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();

            // Identify all the table cell's(td)
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            // Retrive Jsoup Elements
            // Get the first td
            map.put("rank", tds.get(0).text());
            // Get the second td
            map.put("country", tds.get(1).text());
            // Get the third td
            map.put("population", tds.get(2).text());
            // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
            arraylist.add(map);
          }
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
      // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
      adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
      // Set the adapter to the ListView
      listview.setAdapter(adapter);
      // Close the progressdialog
      mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
}
```

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.kovalev.jsoupkakiepary;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  // Declare Variables
  Context context;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
  ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> data;
  HashMap < String, String > resultp = new HashMap < String, String > ();

  public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
    ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView rank;
    TextView country;
    TextView population;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);


    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
    country.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
    population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
    // Capture ListView item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
        // Pass all data rank
        intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
        // Pass all data country
        intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        // Pass all data population
        intent.putExtra("population", resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
        // Start SingleItemView Class
        context.startActivity(intent);

      }
    });
    return itemView;
  }
}
```

**SingleItemView.java**

```
package com.kovalev.jsoupkakiepary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
  // Declare Variables
  String rank;
  String country;
  String population;
  String position;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the result of rank
    rank = i.getStringExtra("rank");
    // Get the result of country
    country = i.getStringExtra("country");
    // Get the result of population
    population = i.getStringExtra("population");

    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
    TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
    TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);

    // Set results to the TextViews
    txtrank.setText(rank);
    txtcountry.setText(country);
    txtpopulation.setText(population);
  }
}
```

Просто не понимаю как сделать, чтобы выбрало таблицу внутри таблицы. Вот [ссылка](http://www.kakiepary.ru/archive/num/45/) на страницу, которую пытаюсь отпарсить.
Помогите чем сможете и поподробнее, если можно.

Answer (score 1):

У вас

```
for (Element table: doc.select("table[id=child_time]")) {}
```

А на странице

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="child_time" width="100%" align="center"></table>
```

**ID** != **class**

Для того чтобы обработать все "одноклассные" таблицы используя jsoup нужно использовать итератор. Примерно так

```
Iterator<Element> tbIter = doc.select("table[class=child_time]")
        .iterator();
while (tbIter.hasNext()) {}
```

Comment: Изменил, но все-равно не работает. В чем еще может быть дело. Таблиц с классом child_time там куча. как выбрать чтобы первую выбирало. что необходимо добавить

Comment: @AlexeyKovalev смотри дополнение к ответу

Comment: а куда его вставлять и как можно использовать?